# How to create system user in Sling?

Tags: sling, jackrabbit

How can I create a system user in Sling?

I tried searching but all I find is related to AEM, which I don't use. Is it possible to create the user using Jackrabbit API or Sling Initial Content (descriptor files)?

I tried to execute the following:

`curl -u admin:admin -F:name=myuser -Fpwd=mypwd -FpwdConfirm=mypwd -Frep:principalName=myuser -Fjcr:primaryType=rep:SystemUser http://localhost:8080/home/users/system/*`

But there is an error:

```
*ERROR* [127.0.0.1 [1465215465364] POST /home/users/system/* HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation Exception during response processing.
javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: Property is protected: rep:principalName = myuser
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.NodeDelegate.setProperty(NodeDelegate.java:525)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl$35.perform(NodeImpl.java:1358)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl$35.perform(NodeImpl.java:1346)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.perform(SessionDelegate.java:209)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.ItemImpl.perform(ItemImpl.java:112)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl.internalSetProperty(NodeImpl.java:1346)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl.setProperty(NodeImpl.java:432)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.helper.SlingPropertyValueHandler.store(SlingPropertyValueHandler.java:592)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is possible through a post request per: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/sling-users/201512.mbox/%3CCAFMYLMb9Wiy+DYmacc5oT7YRWT1hth8j1XAAo_sKT8uq9HoFNw@mail.gmail.com%3E

The suggested solution is to use the jackrabbit api to do this. This would look something like:

```
//get a user manager

try {
    User systemUser = userManager.createSystemUser("myuser", "/home/users/system");
} catch (Exception e) {
     log.error("Error adding user",e);
     throw e;
}

//commit changes
```

It's very important to note that this doesn't allow you to set a password for this user, nor can one be set with user.changePassword() -- when I try that I get an error:

```
javax.jcr.UnsupportedRepositoryOperationException: system user
```

From the java doc:

> Create a new system user for the specified userID. The new authorizable is required to have the following characteristics:
>
> - User.isSystemUser() returns true.
> - The system user doesn't have a password set and doesn't allow change the password.

http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.10/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/security/user/UserManagerImpl.html

Here's my whole activator class: https://gist.github.com/scrupulo/61b574c9aa1838da37d456012af5dd50

Answer (score 3):

There is an out-of-the box solution based on Sling and Jackrabbit Oak. It features a text-based DSL for setting users and ACLs, for instance:

```
create service user bob,alice

set ACL on /libs,/apps
    remove * for alice
    allow jcr:read for bob
end
```

It is also possible to embed these instructions in the provisioning model used to build a Sling launchpad - assuming you're using the `slingstart-maven-plugin`.

The complete documentation can be found at [Repository Initializers and Repository Initialization Language](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/repository-initialization.html)

Comment: Will keep an eye on this. I have a use case where I was doing this just this week, but using the AccessControlUtils from jackrabbit. Mine works fine, but being able to write out a set of commands would be an interesting solution.

Comment: I see that the solution has been released, which is great. @bstockwell, you might be interested in it.